# BigQuery Slot Divide Within A project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We have large Big query Datasets where user can run the queries on various table from different datasets.

Currently we have limited slots in our GCP project. We want to have quota limit for our user at `Dataset level`, i.e for a particular datasets we should have threshold quota, so we optimize the use of slots and also prevent our system from abusing.

In GCP is there any way via which we can assign quota to Datasets or other optimal way to divide quota to table or datasets.

Answer (score 0):

There are documentation as well as guidelines about BigQuery [quotas & limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas). You can manipulate the limits under IAM & admin >> Quotas for project "projectid" >> Filter by Bigquery API.

As this is a particular case, very specific scenario of your project bigquery dataset, I suggest you to go [1:1 support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub). Also, You can request a feature for it on google [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685).

As a final note, a possible solution will be to have a new project. Under the new project scope, reduce the quotas and limits for all BigQuery datasets that you want to have reduced capabilities.

Comment: Hello @Marcin, were you able to check my answer?